# React typeerror in axios callback TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I know lots of questions are related to this already on stack overflow but I am new to react and also stack overflow and I couldn't find any solution So, I'm stuck. so every time I tried to implement this code i got TypeError: this.setState is not a function error and the code is already in ES6. The error is occurring on this line : ***this.setState({token : true});***. I don't know how to set state in there. I've bind the loginSubmit function to **this** but it is still not working...

```
  import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username : '',
            password : '',
            token : false
        }
        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
        this.loginSubmit = this.loginSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if(token!==null && token!==undefined){
            this.setState({token : true});
        }
    }
    onChangeHandler(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.id]:event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.username,this.state.password);
    }
    loginSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let loginFormData = new FormData();
        loginFormData = {
            'username' : this.state.username,
            'password' : this.state.password
        }
        axios({
            method : 'post',
            url : 'http://localhost:3001/loginApi',
            data : loginFormData
        })

        .then((response)=>{

            if(response.data.msg=="database error"){
                console.log("database error");
            }
            if(response.data.msg=="no user found username or password incorrect"){
                console.log("no user found username or password incorrect");
            }
            if(response.data.msg=="jwt error"){
                console.log("jwt error");
            }
            if(response.status==200 && response.data.result!=null && response.data.result!=undefined && response.data.token!=null && response.data.token!=undefined){
                console.log("user logged in && loginapi response.data.result:",response.data.result,response.data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('token',response.data.token);
                this.setState({token : true});
            }
        })
        .catch((response)=>{
            console.log("catch response api call fail:",response);
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
        });
        this.setState = {
            username : '',
            password : ''
        }
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.token){
            return <Redirect to='/profile' />
        }
        return(
            <>
            <div className="all">
                <div className="sidenav">
                    <div className="login-main-text">
                        <h2>Application<br/> Login Page</h2>
                        <p>Login from here to access.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="main">
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div className="login-form">
                            <form>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>User Name</label>
                                    <input name="username" id="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event)} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="User Name"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input name="password" id="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event)} type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                                </div>
                                <button name='logionSubmit' id='logionSubmit' onClick={(event)=>this.loginSubmit(event)} type="submit" className="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

and because of this the automatic redirection is not working I've to refresh page every time to redirect to profile. The redirection code is below.

```
   render(){
        if(this.state.token){
            return <Redirect to='/profile' />
        }
        return( and then some jsx code goes here);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

[You are re-assiging](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) `this.setState` when its need to be treated as immutable:

```
this.setState = {
  username: "",
  password: "",
};
```

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

And then calling `this.setState` asynchronousely in `axios`.

---

Without producible example, it may be because [you didn't bind `loginSubmit` to `this` instance.](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)

> There are several ways to make sure functions have access to component attributes like `this.props` and `this.state`, depending on which syntax and build steps you are using.

```
// Class Properties
loginSubmit = (event) => {
  ...
}
```

Or bind it within the constructor:

```
// Bind in constructor
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.loginSubmit = this.loginSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: i bind it like u said already but it is not working. sorry i forgot to mention that i am new to this so hope you understand

Comment: You need to ask a complete question, please read how: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why you trying to assign something to `this.setState`, try removing it.

Comment: sorry i am new to this i've put whole code this time and updated it.

Comment: I updated the answer... Next time post a minimal example as expected

Comment: if i remove this.setState then how to redirect to profile as i mention in the question any alternative solution if you know... @DennisVash

Comment: Please read the docs, you need to treat state as immutable, the problem is with the assigning `this.setStaet =...`

Comment: For a new question post another question, this line is useless anyways

Comment: You were right thanks for the solution.. @DennisVash

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code because you need to share more of it, this could be because you need to call `super(props)` inside the class constructor.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention that but i already did that but still not working i have updated the code with full code now u can review it